# How to keep PlaceholderText when Textbox get focus WP 8.1 Universal app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to keep PlaceholderText in the Textbox when it gets the cursor (focused) like in the MSN Weather app image.
How can I achieve this?

[image: msn weather]

Comment: you try "Textbox.GotFocus()" event. In that event keep the text that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample code:

```
private void txtname_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtname.Text = "ABCD";
    //txtname.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
}
```

Comment: Ummm sure, but if the user starts writting the text would remain in the control? I don't want it to happen....

Comment: what you are saying, I dont get it. If user starts writing, do you need text written or not?

Comment: If the user starts writting I need the "PlaceHolderTerxt" (not "Text") to disappear as it supposes to do.

Comment: then try "Textbox.TextChanged event, brother

Comment: Ok, I just was wondering if there would be a more elegant solution than being playing with "TextChanged, GotFocus, etc" events. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TextChanged Event:

```
private void txtname_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //txtname.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put the textbox over a textblock and make the textbox's background transparent.

Then bind the Visibility of the Textblock to the Text of the TextBox using a converter. Have the converter return Visible when the Text.Length is 0, otherwise Hidden

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Watermark" 
               Visibility=
                   "{Binding ElementName=Input, 
                             Path=Text, 
                             Converter={StaticResource TextToVisibility}}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Input"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hey that's a very nice one, I will try it, thanks. And +1 for the converter idea :)